# Page load does not work using html5 mode and passing parameter in route

Tags: angularjs

Passing parameters in routeprovider does not load the page on page refresh.
Error message: Unexpected token <

http://localhost:1234/test/188

Here is the example:

```
    .when("/test/:testid", {
                    templateUrl: "Templates/test.html",
                    controller: "testController"})
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

have <base href="/" /> in head section
in web.config i am using 
<!--<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteRules" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url =".*"/>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>-->
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!